# azure logic apps schema validation enable/disable option

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am using HTTP control triggger with recurrence set on it and when I do settings on it, I cant seem to find schema validation enable or disable option on it. 
[image]

Problem is my JSON validation fails almost after every 5 calls because one or the other required field is missing from the http response.

I need to be able to disable schema validation and I just don't see it in the HTTP trigger I put together.

What am I missing here folks. I have another HTTP action and in that too I cant find schema validation enable/disable option.

I am using Azure Portal to create the logic app. I was looking at this post and shows that schema validation should be present on HTTP action or trigger.
https://www.danrigby.com/2018/08/27/enable-schema-validation-and-required-fields-in-logicapps/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the trigger you created is "[HTTP Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#add-an-http-trigger)", it doesn't have "schema validation" setting. The document you provided refers to "[When a HTTP request is received](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres#add-request-trigger)" trigger which has "schema validation" setting, they are two different triggers.

Comment: That interesting, the trigger I need is HTTP trigger and not when a request is received. I need to use recurrence as a trigger and make a call not when a request is received.  Interesting thing is both use JSON and schema validation. Why would have one validation option available and other does not.

Comment: Hi @Sarah, as this question was answered, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks~ And in your another post, if still have problems, please provide more details, I will try to help you in it.

Comment: Hi @Hury, the question is not answered. HTTP trigger doesn't have schema validation but what is the work around it? I need to use HTTP Trigger.  I am still waiting to get help on it.

Comment: Hi @Sarah, this question is about the schema validation in HTTP trigger, but the answer is HTTP trigger doesn't have schema validation. I found you have created another post for the question about disable schema validation, but I'm confused about that how does the HTTP trigger do schema validation in your logic, because the HTTP trigger works fine when I test it in my side(whether the response is json or just a string). So I asked for some more details in that post, could you please provide more information in that post and I will try to help you further.

Comment: Your another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082415/schema-update-validation-fails-azure-logic-apps

Answer (score 0):

The Logic App trigger you are using is an "HTTP Trigger". Find the below image and it does not have the Schema validation option.
[image]

Settings of HTTP trigger which doesn't contain schema validation option. 
[image]

Now, you need to change your trigger from HTTP to "When an HTTP request is received"
[image]

In the settings option, you can find the "**schema validation option**" and turn off it.
[image]

Comment: That interesting, the trigger I need is HTTP trigger and not when a request is received. I need to use recurrence as a trigger and make a call not when a request is received. Interesting thing is both use JSON and schema validation. Why would have one validation option available and other does not