# Schema update validation fails Azure logic apps

Tags: json, azure, jsonschema, azure-logic-apps

In my Logic app I am using HTTP trigger which fires every 3 hours and using a get request on it. After the API responds, the parse JSON call does schema validation. So far with HTTP trigger and Parse JSON, I don't know a way to disable validation of JSON. I know 'when HTTP request is received' as disable validation option but in my case I don't need 'When http request is recieved', I need HTTP trigger on recurrence basis.

Here are my two questions
1) Is there a way to disable schema validation when using HTTP trigger that fires every so often on recurrence basis?

2)
The API calls that we make to a company, it seems like the company frequently updates their JSON return schema. On Monday the calls were going through correctly, on Tuesday, they were not. Upon asking them, this is their response.
"But almost all changes are "adding", rather than "removing" or "renaming" endpoints and information.  I.e. the changes are backward compatible."

My question is adding to schema.. is the validation supposed to fail upon addition because logic app for sure is not validating their additions whereas their representative makes it sound like 'adding' should be backwards compatible. Do addition in schema's cause validation to fail?

I am learning Azure logic apps and not familiar with all components at hand.
What is the best way to handle JSON parsing in case schema changes frequently and how to turn it off if that is a solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Sarah, could you please provide some more details of you logic app(such as the screenshots of the HTTP trigger and Parse JSON action, and the screenshot of error message). I test it in my side, everything works fine even though I add or remove a field of the api's response json.

Comment: Hi Hury, I am updating my question, if you notice that the errors are coming because JSON schema changes and logic apps are not able to handle changes.

Answer (score 0):

In your second screenshot, it seems there is nothing to do with the "HTTP Trigger". The problem is caused by the schema in "Parse JSON"(Parse Organization and Group Information) action. You need to confirm with the company and unify the structure of the json data with them.

In your first screenshot, I think you need to confirm with the company if they have the array in the response json data. Apart from this, we can judge if the array exists and then do the "Select" action, shown as below:

[image]
The fx expression in the "Condition" is:

```
empty(body('Parse_JSON')?['array'])
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thanks Hury, my original question was about schema validation on http trigger. And I mentioned that the company is not giving any confirmation that there would be no additions in schema on regular basis. Bottom line is if http trigger would give me an option to disable validation, these issues wont come even if the end company keep updating their schema every second day.

Comment: I do think that it is a limitation on part of HTTP trigger to force schema validation whereas 'When an http request is received' trigger does not require that. Both are capable of parsing JSON, one forces it and other has the option to disable validation.